# Redirect not happening After button click but same code works from Dev Tools Console

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have the following JS function:

```
        function cancelClick() {
            location.replace('Employers_Welcome.aspx');
            return false;
        };
```

And then I have the following htmllocated within an ASP.NET WebForms page:

```
            <div class="divTableCell-2">
                <div class="field-container">
                    <button id="CancelBtn" class="ViewLogButton buttonStyle" onclick="cancelClick()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I click on the button the cancelClick() function is reached ( I can see this in the Debugger). However the redirection does not occur and instead the page just reloads.

However, if I instead call cancelCick() directly from the IE11 Dev Tools Console on that same page the redirect works.

What am I missing? For what it is worth I have tried different variations of the actual JS redirect code (document.href, location.href etc) and I got the same outcome with all of them.

Comment: Is this button inside a form? it could be posting the form since you don't have a `type=button` attribute on the button.

Comment: @HanYolo Yes it is inside the form on that particular WebForm page. Does the button tag not convey that it is of type button?

Comment: The button by default is of type submit.

Comment: @HanYolo Yup that sorted it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button may be in a form. Given that the default type of a button is [sumbit](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) the form is being submitted and the page reloads. Adding a `type=button` will remove the default submit behavior from the button.